# BeautifulSoup - how to call on a nested element

Tags: python

I just need a little help finding an element in my python script with Beautiful Soup.

Below is the html:

```
<div class="lg-7 lg-offset-1 md-24 sm-24 cols">
<div class="row pr__prices">
<div class="lg-24 md-12 cols">
<input id="analytics_prodPrice_47187" type="hidden" value="2.91">
<div class="pr__pricepoint">
   <div id="product_price" class="pr__price">
      <span class="pound">
      £</span>3<span class="pence">.49<span class="incvat">INC VAT</span></span>
      <span class="price__extra">(<span id="unit_price">£11.26</span>/<span id="unit_price_measure">Ltr</span>)</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do is get the product price, and looking at the html above, it looks like it is found within this section from the html above (price is £3.49):

```
   <div id="product_price" class="pr__price">
      <span class="pound">
      £</span>3<span class="pence">.49<span class="incvat">INC VAT</span></span>
      <span class="price__extra">(<span id="unit_price">£11.26</span>/<span id="unit_price_measure">Ltr</span>)</span>
   </div>
```

My issue is that even though I use Beautiful Soup to try and get the price like so:

```
pound = soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'pound'})
pence = soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'pence'})
prices.append(pound.text + pence.text)
```

I get this exception stating:

```
 prices.append(pound.text + pence.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

So to me it looks like it's returning a None or null. Does anybody have an idea on how I can get to the element?

**EDIT**

Looking at the answers below, I tried to replicate them but instead of using a static HTML, I call on the website url. What I noticed is that even though the code works for a static html, it doesn't work when I call on the url that contains the page that contains that html.

CODE:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.screwfix.com/p/no-nonsense-sanitary-silicone-white-310ml/47187').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
currency = soup.select_one('span.pound')
currency_str = next(currency.strings).strip()

pound_str = currency.nextSibling

pence = soup.select_one('span.pence')
pence_str = next(pence.strings).strip()

print(f"{currency_str}{pound_str}{pence_str}")  # £3.49
```

Error:

```
 currency_str = next(currency.strings).strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strings'
```

Comment: Have you tried printing what's in `data`? Perhaps do `resp = requests.get(...)` then `print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)` to see what the site gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a different approach.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<div class="lg-7 lg-offset-1 md-24 sm-24 cols">
<div class="row pr__prices">
<div class="lg-24 md-12 cols">
<input id="analytics_prodPrice_47187" type="hidden" value="2.91">
<div class="pr__pricepoint">
   <div id="product_price" class="pr__price">
      <span class="pound">
      £</span>3<span class="pence">.49<span class="incvat">INC VAT</span></span>
      <span class="price__extra">(<span id="unit_price">£11.26</span>/<span id="unit_price_measure">Ltr</span>)</span>
   </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
currency = soup.select_one('span.pound')
currency_str = next(currency.strings).strip()

pound_str = currency.nextSibling

pence = soup.select_one('span.pence')
pence_str = next(pence.strings).strip()

print(f"{currency_str}{pound_str}{pence_str}")  # £3.49
```

Comment: Hey, Justin, thank you for your answer. The code works with a static html but when I connect with a url, it doesn't work (please see edit in question for details) :)

Comment: Your right, it was givingme a 403 on the request and it was dueto the user agent missing

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your data as html so what approach you can follow get the text with in that div and use `strip` to remove unnecessary data now if you see main_div contain some letters so remove it by using `re` and you finally get your desired output

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
main_div=soup.find("div",attrs={"class":"pr__price"}).get_text(strip=True)

lst=re.findall("\d+", main_div)
print(".".join(lst[:2]))
```

Output:

```
3.49
```

Comment: Hi Bhavya, I just have a question, and apologies as I am still learning python. The code above with the join. Would that work with dynamic price, example the decimal point is different because it may be 10.99 or 100.99?

Comment: Yes it will work because it create a list of digits, ex. if you have price as 100.99 it will create list as `[100,99,....]`  and you can join first 2 elements from i t

Comment: I have given it an upvote :) Thank you Bhavya